# perl перехватить сигнал

Tags: perl, ipc

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use POSIX ();

my $sigset = POSIX::SigSet->new(POSIX::SIGHUP);
$SIG{HUP}=\&cleanup;

sub cleanup{
    print "ALRM!\n";
}

while (1){
   sleep 1;
}
```

запускаю программу и открываю другой терминал, в котором нахожу через `ps auxww | grep s.pl` пид скрипта

далее делаю `kill 1 12345` - посылаю сигнал `sighup` своему скрипту чтобы посмотреть как отработает обработчик сигналов в нем

и в первом терминале процесс завершается, хотя по моей хотелке должно написать `ALRM!` на `stdout`

что делать? как быть? кто виноват?

Comment: Вот прямо так и пишите `kill 1 12345` ? без знака `-` перед 1 ? и как оно вам только init и всю систему вместе с ним не убивает ....

Comment: ага, на продакшн сервере, из под рута =) надо было писать  kill -HUP 12345 =) все заработало =)

Comment: просто гдето вычитал, что sighup имеет номер 1, потому и того

Comment: Ну да, он первый, только kill принимает или название или номер сигнала, но обязательно с минусом, что бы от pid отличить. Так что `kill -1 12345` аналогично -HUP

Answer (score 1):

> хотя по моей хотелке должно написать ALRM! на stdout

Запустил ваше программу и всё замечательно работает.

```
$ uname -a
Linux kes-desktop 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

У вас какая система??

Распечатайте список всех сигналов, которые поддерживает ваша система и перл может перехватить их:

```
local $, = "\n";
print sort keys %SIG;
```

Comment: Написали же в комментариях что дело в пропущенном дефисе перед номером сигнала.